# Remix Unresponsive - How to recover files that were not downloaded?

Tags: remix

So I had a lot of files saved, Remix is unresponsive and I don't want to exit the page and lose my files. What should I do?
I saved it in Remix but didn't download my files after the changes I made.

I wish I had fixed the local server :(

UPDATE: I just closed the window and opened remix again. All my files where there since they had been saved in the local Chrome storage.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I just closed the window and opened remix again. All my files where there since they had been saved in the local Chrome storage.